# EmberJS: Cannot Load Associated Records from Parent Route

Tags: ember.js

I have two models: `Neuron` and `Plot`:

```
App.Neuron = DS.Model.extend
  ...
  plots: DS.hasMany 'plot', {async: true}

App.Plot = DS.Model.extend
  ...
  neuron: DS.belongsTo 'neuron'

BuzsakiViewer.Router.map ->
  @resource 'neurons'
  @resource 'neuron', path: '/neurons/:neuron_id', ->
    @route 'plots'
```

I want to load the plots associated with a neuron. I have done this successfully from the **/neuron/:neuron_id/plots** route. However, I can't get it to work from the **neuron/:neuron_id** route. Below is the code I am using in `setupController`; the goal is to load the plots into a controller property called `theplots`. When I try to iterate over `theplots` in my template though, I get nothing.  What am I doing wrong? I have the feeling it has something to do with the `async` setting on the association.

```
BuzsakiViewer.NeuronRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set 'model', model
    controller.set 'theplots', model.get('plots')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just accessing `plots` in the template?  If your controller extends ObjectController all properties that don't exist on the controller will be proxied down to the model.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uwENUbeh/2/edit

Comment: Thanks again @kingpin2k...  Can't believe I missed that one. I'm still curious though as to why what I was doing didn't work.